# How to get FB Like to display message

Tags: windows, facebook, facebook-like

I have added the FB Like button to a web page using the process described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). The button renders OK, however I expected it to render the *Be the first of your friends to like this page* message, however it does not. I have played around with the different layout styles, send button and show faces options, and even different browsers (IE8, FF, Chrome) however nothing seems to work. If I want that message to display on the page when the page has not been liked yet, what do I need to do? Is the message something that is only displayed with the iFrame version of the FB API? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to like a web site or Facebook page?

Comment: I'm sorry it's taken so long to respond. I was able to get the button to render, but to answer your question, I was trying to add the like button to a web page on my web site.

Answer (score 1):

I must have mis-copied the generated tag the first time around, because I was able to get the message to render after I re-copied it. Also wanted to mention that you have to be logged into FB in order to get the *Be the first of your friends to like this page* message. If you are not logged in, then a different message will be rendered instead.